# jQuery event handler functions - how to pass my own parameter

Tags: jquery

This is actual code, how do I pass `list[i].fnctn` correctly to the click handler?

`list[i].fnctn` - Contains the name of the function that I want to attach to the click event handler.

```
function createList(list){
    var parentID = $("#content_nav ul");
    var len = list.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />',{text:list[i].text});
        var liElement = jQuery('<li />',{"class":"navlink_"+(i+1),id:"navlink_"+(i+1)});
        //anchorElement.attr('onclick',list[i].fnctn+"()"); - Works fine on desktop browsers but doesn't work on mobile devices. (Mobile devices are my target platform

        anchorElement.on('click',function(event) {
            return window[list[i].fnctn](event); // Here I am getting the error - cannot access property fnctn of undefined
        });
        liElement.append(anchorElement);
        parentID.append(liElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work just fine. You should try it before writing comments like "will cause an error"

Comment: @Esailija : I am creating the `li` elements dynamically. And the name of the function that I want to attach to `click` event of these elments is retrieved from the `json` object. I am attaching these events in a loop, and inside that loop I am getting the error that you cannot access property of undefined.

Comment: Show your *real* code then, the code you gave works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that help, I am not sure if this is possible with the `.on()` method.

```
var message = 'Some value that I want to access inside handler function';


$('#myHandler').click({msg: message},function(e){
    alert(e.data.msg);
});
```

**Edited:**

As xiaowl mentioned. Changing my code for your scenario.

```
function myFunction(){
    var message= "Some value that I want to access inside handler function";
    $("#myHandler").on('click', {msg: message}, function(e){
        alert("I want to alert the value - " + e.data.msg);
    });
}
```

**For the actual Condition**

```
function createList(list){
    var parentID = $("#content_nav ul");
    var len = list.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />',{text:list[i].text});
        var liElement = jQuery('<li />',{"class":"navlink_"+(i+1),id:"navlink_"+(i+1)});
        anchorElement.on('click',{myFunction: list[i]}, function(event) {
            return window[event.data.myFunction](event);
        });
        liElement.append(anchorElement);
        parentID.append(liElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

> .on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
>
> **events** One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".
>
> **selector** A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.
>
> **data** Data to be passed to the handler in `event.data` when an event is triggered.
>
> **handler(eventObject)** A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return false.

So, in your handler, using `event.data['xyz']` to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't related to passing parameters, but scope. `i` will be `=== len` after the loop and all functions are referring to the same `i`, which isn't even an index in the array.

Try with `$.each` since it transparently gives you a free closure:

```
function createList(list) {

    var parentID = $("#content_nav ul");

    $.each(list, function(i, v) {
        var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />', {
            text: v.text
        });
        var liElement = jQuery('<li />', {
            "class": "navlink_" + (i + 1),
            id: "navlink_" + (i + 1)
        });
        anchorElement.on('click', function(event) {
            return window[v.fnctn](event); // Here I am getting the error - cannot access property fnctn of undefined
        });
        liElement.append(anchorElement);
        parentID.append(liElement);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah right... :) Thats my main question, how can I pass that value within that function. I got that working now :)
Thanks....

Comment: @AdityaParab your problem wasn't passing but scope, `for` loop doesn't have its own scope so you are using the same `i` for all the handlers. Using this should work and is imo simpler as well.

Comment: @esailijia : Thanks :)
Got it running. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myHandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.foo);
}

$("p").on("click", {foo: "bar"}, myHandler)
```

Here is an examples: http://api.jquery.com/on/

In your version, i think:

```
function myFunction(){

    var xyz = "Some value that I want to access inside handler function";

    $("#myHandler").on('click', {msg: xyz}, function(event){

        alert("I want to alert the value - " + event.data.msg);
        //Error is logged in console as xyz is undefined.

    });
}

myFunction();
```

Upd: Works fine.

Upd2: Here is working above example of your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/kjLmm/

Upd3: So, you could just pass your list element as parameter like in examples above:

```
anchorElement.on('click', {element: list[i]}, function(event) {
            return window[event.data.element.fnctn](event); // Here I am getting the error - cannot access property fnctn of undefined
        });
```

Comment: @Fsoul According your page the use of onclick as the OP posted is also allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I selected `Talha Ahmed Khan` for answering that first :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match values, try this:

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DVhpj/1/)

```
function myFunction(){

    var xyz = "Some value that I want to access inside handler function";

    $(document).on('click','#myHandler',function(event){

        var takeId = this.id;

        if ( takeId === xyz ) {
           alert("your id is equal to"+xyz);
           //Error is logged in console as xyz is undefined.
        }else{
           alert("your id is not equal to"+xyz);
        }

    });
}

$(function() {//dont forgot to call function
    myFunction();
});
```